# ¿Como configurar el depurador de Vs Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio, depuración

Estoy programando en java, resulta que cuando voy a depurar mi proyecto, el depurador recorre todos los procesos internos del JDK de java, se hace muy lento depurar así.

Como lo configuro para que se saltee lo que hace el JDK por dentro. O sea que solo recorra las clases de mi proyecto. He buscado en internet y parece ser q se puede hacer poniendo lo siguiente en el settings.json del Vs Studio Code:

```
"java.debug.settings.stepping.skipClasses": [
    "java.lang.ClassLoader",
    "$JDK"
]
```

Sin embargo, lo he puesto y sigue funcionando igual, no se si estoy haciendo algo mal, o si no es lo que necesitó.

Para dar un ejemplo de lo que me refiero con las clases internas del JDK es esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi esta mi Settings:

```
{
"editor.minimap.renderCharacters": false,
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Eclipse Dark",
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#293df19f"
},
"explorer.confirmDelete": false,
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnType": true,
"diffEditor.codeLens": true,
"appworks.materialSources": [],
"debug.terminal.clearBeforeReusing": true,
"git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
"java.debug.settings.stepping.skipClasses": [
    "$Libraries",
    "java.lang.ClassLoader",
    "$JDK"
]
```

Comment: Según como funciona el [depurador](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-actions) de vscode, intuyo que estas seleccionado "Step Into" (tercer botón del depurador), y lo que realmente quieres que haga es un simple "Continue" (primer botón). Al menos en mi caso se presenta el comportamiento que describes cuando selecciono el tercer botón, y el comportamiento que quieres cuando selecciono el primero, acorde también a la documentación.

Comment: Nono, justamente ese es el problema, estoy apretando el boton "Step Over", que es para saltar al método siguiente. Pero salta literalmente al "método siguiente", entrando así en las clases del JDK y recorriendo un montón de métodos, que obviamente no me interesan, puesto q lo que quiero debugear es mi programa, no el JDK. Usando NetBeans te saltaba al próximo método de tu proyecto. Cómo puse ahí, puedes evitar eso usando unos filtros, q se ponen con ese comando que mostré ahí, pero sin embargo no me funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que es un error de la extensión de Microsoft del depurador de Java de VS Code, ya hice el reporte en su GitHub, lo pueden ver aquí: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/1367